# How do I implement lumped circuit elements in ANSYS HFSS v15.0?

Tags: antenna, simulation, pcb-antenna, tuning, lumped

I am simulating a PCB antenna using ANSYS HFSS v15.0. Before the signal is fed into the antenna, there is a smoothing capacitor and an LC T-section matching network to match the impedance of the 50 Ω trace to the antenna.

I am aware that there is the option of using the LumpedRLC boundary, but how do I implement 4 different discrete circuit elements (2 capacitors and 2 inductors) using HFSS when it only allows me to connect different surfaces to each other if they are part of the same LumpedRLC boundary i.e. having the same R,L and C values? The version of HFSS that I am using doesn't allow me to export the antenna into a lumped circuit analysis software.

[image: Error message when I try to make the current flow line]